# Get all class names in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to check how many `<div class="topology-list">` I have using Angular. At the moment, there are three

I have tried:

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.topology-list')).length
```

This logs `1` (should be 3)

```
document.querySelectorAll('.topology-list')
```

Logs `1` too

```
document.getElementsByClassName('topology-list');
```

The last one logs an object with the 3 items, but if I add `.length` it logs `1`

[image]

Comment: is this all css classes is within the same html page?

Comment: Yes, all `<div>` with class `topology-list`

Comment: Do you create elements with this class with AngularJS? You have to wait AngularJS made it. You have to wait digest process, you have to use $timeout with 0 second. Could you paste the code?

Comment: You are absolutely right @Laurianti ; Used the first one with a `$timeout` and it logs three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directive "your-directive" and put it to the outermost of the HTML

Try the above selections in your directive and all of them should give the correct result.

```
<body ng-app="yourAppName">
  <div your-directive>
    <!-- Here your all controllers are loaded-->
  </div>
</body>
```